# How to log scrape paths rvest used?

Tags: r, rvest

**Background:** Using `rvest` I'd like to scrape all details of all art pieces for the painter Paulo Uccello on wikiart.org. The endgame will look something like this:

```
> names(uccello_dt)
[1] title  year  style  genre  media  imgSRC  infoSRC
```

**Problem:** When a scraping attempt doesn't go as planned, I get back `character(0)`. This isn't helpful for me in understanding exactly what path the scrape took to get `character(0)`. I'd like to have my scrape attempts output what path it specifically took so that I can better troubleshoot my failures.

**What I've tried:**
I use Firefox, so after each failed attempt I go back to the web inspector tool to make sure that I am using the correct css selector / element tag. I've been keeping the rvest documentation by my side to better understand its functions. It's been a trial and error that's taking much longer than I think should. Here's a cleaned up source of 1 of many failures:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(rvest)

sample_url <-
 read_html(
"https://www.wikiart.org/en/paolo-uccello/all-works#!#filterName:all-paintings-chronologically,resultType:detailed"
)

imgSrc <-
  sample_url %>% 
  html_nodes(".wiki-detailed-item-container") %>% html_nodes(".masonry-detailed-artwork-item") %>% html_nodes("aside") %>% html_nodes(".wiki-layout-artist-image-wrapper") %>% html_nodes("img") %>%
  html_attr("src") %>%
  as.character()

title <-
  sample_url %>% 
  html_nodes(".masonry-detailed-artwork-title") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. What do you mean with 'when a scraping attempt fails'? If the web-page is unavailable, an error will be thrown. If an item that you are looking for cannot be found, it cannot be found, and there is no clear reason. If you want to know where in your pipeline no item is returned, you should split up your pipeline into parts (store the result every `html_nodes()` call separately). If it 'fails', you can inspect those parts and see where it went wrong.

Comment: That said, the data you are looking for is available in JSON format: https://www.wikiart.org/en/paolo-uccello/mode/all-paintings?json=2&layout=new&page=1&resultType=detailed. You can easily load this in using, for example, `jsonlite`. This doesn't answer your question but it does give you the data you need in a structured form.

Comment: @Bas I'm sorry for being unclear; by failed scraping attempt, I meant "a scraping attempt that doesn't go as planned" which I've just edited the post to clarify. Thank you for the pointer to look at the JSON file. Getting the data was a lot easier using `jsonlite`. Appreciate it greatly!